# Modelling actions in REST

Tags: api, http, rest

I'm making a REST interface to a management system (let's call this system A) for network equipment and I have everything working. A fetches the equipment information from another backend system (let's call this system B) and index it in a database and then whenever a client asks for the information over the REST interface it returns it as JSON.

However sometimes a client needs to forcefully make A refresh some equipment information by requesting it from B (without the client being involved besides asking A to refresh it). Refreshing the information for a single node takes several seconds so the information should probably not be returned in the same request as in which it is requested. Currently we've modeled this as that you create a job of a "refresh information" type using `POST /jobs` with some data. But this feels very over engineered and we'd much rather want something like `POST /equipment/<id>/refresh` but this feels to go against the "REST way"?

Is there any other solution to this than the one mentioned with jobs above but still follow the "REST way"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `GET /equipment/<id>?since=<timestamp>`, where the `since` parameter is optional.  Semantically this means:

- Get the equipment with the given `id` as of whenever it happened to be last refreshed (when `timestamp` not given), or
- Get the equipment with the given `id` refreshed no earlier than the given `timestamp`

Each `equipment` in your system would have a `last_refreshed` timestamp. The `GET` with the `since=<timestamp>` parameter would refresh the equipment if `last_refreshed < since` and then return the `equipment`.

A user of your service could then say `GET /equipment/123?since=<15 minutes ago>` and be sure they're always getting info that's no older than 15 minutes. `GET /equipment/123?since=<now>` means "force a refresh."

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Thanks! I've coupled it with returning a 202 status code if the information has to be refreshed (it takes a few seconds, i updated the question to reflect that).

Comment: That's an acceptable way to use the 202 "Accepted" status code - just make sure you clearly document that this is a possible response to this `GET` request.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `POST` in Rest services means that you will create some object.

To refresh one object, or update, it's recommended the `PUT` method.

Like um CRUD, when you have `Create`, `Read`, `Update`, and `Delete`, in REST will be `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE` (in order).

Maybe in your case the best URL for this is a `PUT` to `/equipment/<id>`.

URLs:

`POST to /equipment/` : Create equipment

`GET to /equipment/<id>`: Read equipment with id `<id>`

`PUT to /equipment/<id>`: Update equipment with id `<id>`

`DELETE to /equipment/<id>`: Delete the equipment with id `<id>`

I hope that solve you doubt.

Anyway, a good reference it's the [Apigee ebooks](http://apigee.com/about/api-best-practices/all/ebook)

Comment: Well yes. That works and is the proper way if the client provides the new information. But in this case the client just asks the system to fetch the new information from another backend system on its own and at least i feel that PUT a regular ``PUT /equipment/<id>`` is the wrong way to go for that.

Comment: Alright. You will return the fecthed informations? Or just for update the database? You can also use a GET, without sending the information, but using `@QueryParam("refresh") boolean refresh` to control when you need to just update the another backend. like a GET request in `/equipments/<id>?refresh=true`

Comment: It would just update the database without returning anything. Using GET like you describe could work but it still feels like it's not really rest or a clean descriptive solution. I feel that there should be some mechanism in HTTP that allows us to describe in a semantic way to perform some action on a resource. But maybe there isn't.

Comment: Yes, maybe there is a gap on rest to explain how to do this on a better way. I think that will be up to you to build and make an documentation to explain... unfortunately there is no 'right' url to do this